# .htaccess Mod Rewrite with multiple Query strings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a mod rewrite for a query string.

I have an url like this :

```
http://test.co.uk/test-app/?option=com_testdetails&view=testingdetail&testhotel=105680&testhotelname=Sheraton%20Tel%20Aviv%20Hotel&testhotellocation=Near%20Gordon%20Beach
```

I have tried

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^option=com_testdetails&view=testingdetail&testhotel=([^&]*)&testhotelname=([^&]*)&testhotellocation=([^&]*)$     [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /([^/]*)/?option=com_testdetails&view=testingdetail&testhotel=([^&]*)&testhotelname=$1&testhotellocation=$2 [L]
```

but the above does not work and i have tested this with

```
`http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/`and http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php
```

and the result i get is

```
http://test.co.uk/-?option=com_testdetails&view=testingdetail&testhotel=105680&testhotelname=Sheraton Tel Aviv Hotel&testhotellocation=Near Gordon Beach
```

I want the URL to be like

```
 http://test.co.uk/test-app/Sheraton Tel Aviv Hotel/testhotellocation=Near Gordon Beach
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong and it be great if you can help me...

Regards,
Jai

Comment: Why are you matching the `QUERY_STRING` in the first place? (1) That mostly makes sense if you were to redirect old-style to new-style URLs. Adapt your code to generate short links instead. (2) You shouldn't have regex patterns in the rewrite target, but only `$1`, `$2`, … substitutions.